# Why doesn't class B print every 1 second

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Given the code below

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue
from time import sleep

class myClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self,num,q):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.num = num
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.num =  self.num+1
            q.put(self.num)
            sleep(5)

class myClassB(Thread):
    def __init__(self,num,q):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.num = num
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.num = q.get()
            print self.num
            sleep(1)

num = 0
q = Queue.Queue()
myClassA(num,q)
myClassB(num,q)
while True:
    pass
```

Why doesn't Class B print every second? I would expect Class B to print five 1's then five 2's etc. Is `q.get()` a blocking function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Queue.get()` is blocking by default. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get):

> If optional args *block* is true and *timeout* is `None` (**the default**), block if necessary until an item is available.

Bold emphasis mine. Because `q.get()` blocks, it won't return until the other thread has put something in the queue for it to fetch.

Even so, removing an item from the queue means it *won't be there the next time*. `q.get()` doesn't leave the number there to be fetched again and again.

Instead, if you were to use `q.get(False)` (or used [`q.get_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get_nowait)) to prevent blocking, an `Empty` exception is raised instead.

Comment: thanks, case of RTFM again. Doing this seemed to get the desired effect
 `try:
                self.num = q.get(False)
                print self.num
            except:
                print "nothing in queue" 
            sleep(1)`

Comment: @moonraker: at the very least catch the specific exception: `except Queue.Empty:`.